# Implementation of A* Algorithm in a 3D Cube Array

Tags: 3d, algorithm

I am working on making a program that finds the most efficient way to a goal from a starting point, with a few random debris set around. The entire thing is a 25x25x25 3d array of Cube objects, which are self explanatory. There are some random debris in random positions in the cube, along with a single block that acts as the goal.

I just want to know if a 3D implementation of the a* algorithm is possible, because I haven't really seen anything on it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

A* is an algorithm that works on nodes.

- You code your own efficiency function.
- You supply the nodes and the network.

This means that the nodes can be 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, or no d at all and use something else.